# How to get a multiple results from a script

Tags: python, random, pycharm

I'm new to python. I just want a simple app that shuffles submitted figures.

```
import random

figures = list("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
random.shuffle(figures)
print(''.join(figures))

Result: E630938F69F4957AD6DBC12DE28A35F7EA8C6512409BCE0518FB432AC7410B7D
```

This is almost what I wanted. But is it possible to get multiple results without copy-pasting the 3 lines of code? My apologies for the dummy question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/for_loop_range/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a for loop:

```
import random
figures = list("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
for i in range(5):
    random.shuffle(figures)
    print(''.join(figures))
```

prints your random string 5 times

Comment: It is better to exclude the list creation from the for loop.

Comment: also is there any tutorial through which I can write a simple GUI for this. Like I enter the number of the strings and hit enter! And it will display the results. Any tutorial or link is highly appreciated. Thanks.